# Review overview User Interface drawing too much attention to what I can't do

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, user-interface

A recent UI (User Interface) change is taking a lot of real estate in the [Review overview](https://stackoverflow.com/review) for users with less than 2000 or 3000 reputation points. The big blue boxes, as seen here:

[image: Stack]

I don't need the UI to scream my low reputation points at me, and I was irritated enough to make a personal change to revert it. The queues are *already* grayed out and I'm perfectly able to read the information without having it appear so prominent on the page:

[image: Mine]

- Is there a reason for this change, other than a "Oops, we changed something else and this happened to be effected too"?
- Can we roll it back?

[Make all “You need at least 2k/3k reputation to review” banners equally wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351195/make-all-you-need-at-least-2k-3k-reputation-to-review-banners-equally-wide) seems to be related, but is not, in my opinion, focusing on the right thing.

Comment: Looks like they decided that it's [an inlined notice](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/#inline) and thus following the official Stacks' design guideline...